# curl delete in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am a newbie and I am stuck to do delete in curl using Codeigniter.
It is my very first question and I am sorry if I am missing anything.
The followings are my codes and only edit is working (so I left out the codes) but my delete curl isn't working and I am kind of stuck.
Thanks in advance.

The problem is it isn't deleting at all and I think my curl is wrong.

```
    public function function3($data, $hostURL) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $hostURL.'..............');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($http_code =! 200) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    } else {
        return "Deleted";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Please, show us only the code you are having problems with. What does it mean "isn't working", what error do you get? And why are you showing us Another controller/model for deleting?

Comment: I think my curl for delete is wrong as it doesn't delete the number I wanted to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
Your function works well (I've tested it). There are only three possible problems:

1. the script on the page you are calling (`$hostURL`) is broken,
2. your input data (`$data`) has wrong format,
3. you are not reading the right post data on your $hostURL page.

What does the `$data` you are passing to `function3` looks like? It should be something like this:

```
$data = 'param=value&anotherparam=anothervalue';
```

You can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function.

In the file that is handling your DELETE request, you have to use this code to read post data:

```
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Thank for your help :) Your are right the input data was in wrong format.